# Why have my appended objects lost their rigid body settings?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, append

I am working on a scene in which a wrecking ball on a chain crashes through numerous glass cubes.

I created the chain and ball in a different blender file to work more quickly, since the numerous cubes made modelling slow. I created materials for the ball and chain and then made rigid bodies correctly so the chain and ball would swing realistically.

Now that I have appended the chain and ball (About 10 individual objects) from my first blender file into my current file with the glass cubes, the ball and chain no longer move when I press play even though they still appear to have their correct rigid body settings.

It seems that importing multiple objects, each with their own rigid body settings is problematic. Is there any way to get my wrecking ball and chain into my file with the glass cubes without having to remake them within the glass cube file?

Thank you for your time?

Comment: Maybe deleting and resting the rigid body setting on the appended objects will get the to move correctly.

Answer (score 3):

This is because there is no *Rigid body world* in your second file.
To fix this:

1. Press *Add rigid body world* in *Properties > Scene > Rigid body world*:

   [image]
2. With your appended rigid body objects selected, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to make a group. They should now have a green outline:

   [image]
3. Select the group in *Properties > Scene > Rigid Body world > Group*:

   [image]