# Rigid Body World (Groups) Explained

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

When working with rigid bodies I have to deal with the Rigid Body World and Groups in the Rigid Body World. I have done some reading - for instance the manual and [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8805/why-have-my-appended-objects-lost-their-rigid-body-settings/8806#8806) - but it is not very clear to me what is the function of the Rigid Body World "checked" and to have one or more Groups in the Rigid Body World. Who can explain ?

Comment: It could be just a way to experiment with different "worlds", having different properties, comparing effects on "rigid body"- enabled objects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rigid body world contains global settings for the rigid body simulation.

With the "Rigid Body World" checkbox you can simply disable/enable the rigid body simulation.

In order to understand the groups, you have to understand the following:

1. The rigid body system uses regular Blender groups to keep track of the objects that need to be simulated.
2. When you add rigid body physics to the first object, a group called "Rigid Body World" is automatically created, and the object is added to it. You can see it in the Outliner, if you set it to show groups.
3. When you add rigid body physics to other objects, they are also added to the "Rigid Body World" group
4. You can create your own groups, and select them in the "Rigid Body World" panel. In this case the objects belonging to the new group will be simulated and the objects belonging to the old group will be ignored.

Comment: So this means that only one group of objects can be simulated in a simulation ?

Comment: Yes, as I explained in my answer to this question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64208/rigid-body-physics-having-multiple-rigid-body-worlds